# ¿Por qué decimos "grado sexagesimal" si la circunferencia tiene 360 grados y no 60?

Tags: definiciones, expresiones, matemáticas

Una pregunta de matemáticas, para variar. Veo que en la literatura se habla de "[grado sexagesimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grado_sexagesimal)" para medir ángulos en una circunferencia, en oposición al grado centesimal y a los radianes. Extraído del CORDE:

> *En construcción mecánica se utiliza corrientemente como unidad de ángulos el grado sexagesimal, igual a 1/90 del ángulo recto. El grado sexagesimal se indica abreviadamente por °. Se utilizan también, para la medición de ángulos con precisión de fracciones de grado, los submúltiplos de éste.*
>
> - Segundo Estévez Somolinos, "La medición en el taller mecánico. Tomo I. Instrumentos de medida y su uso." España, 1961.

Sin embargo, un [sistema sexagesimal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_sexagesimal) es aquel que emplea como base aritmética el número 60, mientras que una circunferencia tiene 360 grados.

Entiendo el empleo de "minuto sexagesimal" y "segundo sexagesimal", ya que un grado se divide en 60 minutos, y un minuto en 60 segundos. En otros idiomas parece que se emplea simplemente "grado" ([inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)), francés, portugués, en inglés de hecho hablan de que para dividir un grado se puede usar el sistema sexagesimal, pero no trata al grado en sí como sexagesimal), aunque en otros sí que hablan también de "grado sexagesimal" (italiano, alemán). ¿De dónde viene el referirse a algo que es la 1/360 parte de algo como "sexagesimal"?

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/origin-of-360-degrees "Another theory is that the Babylonians subdivided the circle using the angle of an equilateral triangle as the basic unit and further subdivided the latter into 60 parts following their sexagesimal numeric system."

Answer (score 4):

Porque el grado se divide en 60 partes iguales, no por los grados que tenga la circunferencia.

> [**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grado_sexagesimal).
>   Un grado sexagesimal es el ángulo central subtendido por un arco cuya longitud es igual a 1/360 de la circunferencia. 
>   ...
>   El grado sexagesimal, como unidad del sistema de medida de ángulos sexagesimal, está definido partiendo de que un ángulo recto tiene 90° (90 grados sexagesimales), y sus divisores: el minuto sexagesimal y el segundo sexagesimal, están definidos del siguiente modo:
>
> 1 ángulo recto = 90° (grados sexagesimales).
>   1 grado sexagesimal = 60′ (minutos sexagesimales).
>   1 minuto sexagesimal = 60″ (segundos sexagesimales).

Y según el Diccionario de la Lengua Española:

> [**Sexagesimal**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XkoGZcZ):
>   1. adj. Mat. Dicho de un sistema de numeración o de cómputo: **Que tiene como base la división de la unidad en sesenta partes iguales.**

Comment: Por ponerme un poco puntilloso, un "segundo sexagesimal" no se divide en 60 partes, sino en 100 (centésimas de segundo). Luego se llama "segundo sexagesimal" porque es la 1/60 parte de algo más grade. Si tiramos de ahí para arriba, llegamos al "grado sexagesimal" que no es la 1/60 parte de algo más grande, sino la 1/360 parte de algo. Luego me sigue sin cuadrar la explicación.

Comment: Discusión [trasladada al chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47372/discussion-between-user-and-carlos-alejo).

Comment: Si se divide en 60, ¿no debería ser "sesentagesimal"?